# How to set a custom location for a Error Provider

Tags: vb.net, errorprovider

How would you set a custom location for an error provider in VB.Net?

I have tried:

myErrorProvider.SetIconAlignment(myTextBox, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight + 50)

However this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the alignment.  Try a different method: 
`myErrorProvider.SetIconPadding(myTextBox, 50)`